# Does android.webkit.CookieManager works on android 2.3.6？

Tags: android, cookiemanager

I found that android.webkit.CookieManagerworks since api level 9,so I think itwill work since android2.3 inclusive.But recently I found that it didn't work on android2.3.6。

//setcookie

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this.activity);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
cookieManager.setCookie(cookie_url,cookieNameString);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

I have tested it on android3.2 and android4.1.2,and it all works.

Comment: What didn't work?  Did it crash or just not get the expected result?

Comment: just didn't get the expected result.When I load webview,It seems that the cookies have not been set correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think you are seing an android bug:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16543

The [removeAllCookie()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#removeAllCookie%28%29) call starts a thread, which then runs in parallell with the calling thread and may remove the cookies you are adding with [setCookie()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setCookie%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). A work-around is to only delete cookies for specific domains, if you know which those are.

It seems to have been fixed in newer android devices - I could not reproduce the problem on 4.1 or 4.2.